# Rails: Capture the URL that produced ActionController::RoutingError

Tags: error-handling, http-status-code-404, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I am trying to capture the URL that produced a routing error. My end goal is the change the domain on the URL to check if it exists on our old site (changed the domain) and if so redirect to the old site. Here is what I have do far.

```
unless Rails.application.config.consider_all_requests_local
  rescue_from Exception, with: :render_500
  rescue_from ActionController::RoutingError, with: :check_old_site
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownController, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActionController::UnknownAction, with: :render_404
  rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: :render_404
end

private

def check_old_site(exception)
  #Need to edit the URL but I need access to before I can write the code to modify
  captured_and_modified_url = ???
  case Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(captured_and_modified_url)) 
    when Net::HTTPSuccess then redirect_to captured_and_modified_url
    else render_404(exception)
  end
end

def render_404(exception)
  @not_found_path = exception.message
  respond_to do |format|
    format.html { render template: 'errors/error_404', layout: 'layouts/application', status: 404 }
    format.all { render nothing: true, status: 404 }
  end
end
```

So for this question I just want to get at the URL that got to 404 error. Thanks for any help up front.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figure this out a while ago. `request.path`

```
def check_old_site(exception)
  exception_url = "http://old.richarddawkins.net#{request.path}"
  case Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(exception_url))
    when Net::HTTPSuccess then redirect_to exception_url
    else render_404(exception)
  end 
end
```